# How to extends "DisplayNameFor" to display full text in asp.net core?

Tags: asp.net-core, razor

I want to display full property name for "DisplayNameFor" without concatenation.

```
[Display(Name = "Does the information included in this paper is new?")]
        public bool IsNewInfo { get; set; }
```

In the Razor view it appears like this

```
Does the...
```

Comment: By default, the `DisplayNameFor()` won't truncate the `Name`. I doubt whether there's a CSS style like `white-space:nowrap; overflow:hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis;` that makes the `Name` shown with an ellipsis (`...`).

Comment: thank you for your answer as your answer solved my problem .... if you want to add your comment as an  answer and i will assign it as proper answer to my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like there's a `CSS` style  that makes the `Name` shown with an ellipsis (`...`):

```
white-space: nowrap; 
overflow: hidden; 
text-overflow: ellipsis;
```

By default, the `DisplayNameFor()` won't truncate the `Name`.